# Custom Data Annotations for Complex Models

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unobtrusive-javascript

I have a view model like this:

```
public class Event
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DateRangeValidator]
    public DateTimeSpan DateRange { get; set; }
}
```

And this contains another class called `DateTimeSpan` that looks like this:

```
public class DateTimeSpan
{
    public DateTime Start { get; set; }
    public DateTime End { get; set; }
}
```

I want to enable jQuery unobtrusive validation on the client side so I have written a custom data annotation validator (it inherits from `ValidationAttribute` and implements `IClientValidatable`) but it only seems to work if I apply the annotation to the `Start` and `End` properties of the `DateTimeSpan` class, and not if I apply it to the `DateRange` property of the `Event` class.

This is in my view:

```
@Html.LabelFor(x => x.DateRange.Start, "Start Date:") @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.DateRange.Start)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.DateRange.Start)

@Html.LabelFor(x => x.DateRange.End, "End Date:") @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.DateRange.End)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.DateRange.End)
```

ASP.NET MVC 3 will only inject the unobtrusive JavaScript data-* attributes into the HTML if the annotation is added to the `Start` and `End` properties, is there a way to make it work if the property is applied to the `DateRange` property instead?

I don't want my domain model class (`DateRange`, i.e. non view-model classes) to have to implement IClientValidatable because then I have to reference System.Web.Mvc in the domain model project.

Edit: Not sure if it's relevant but the `DateRangeValidator` attribute does checks to make sure the end date occurs after the start date etc.